# How to remove space for email validation error while in email address field in tailwindcss (coded such that error shows only after exiting field)?

Tags: reactjs, validation, functional-programming, tailwind-css, email-validation

Tech: ReactJS and TailwindCSS.

I've made form validation for email using react and tailwindcss. However, even when there's no error message, there's a space for it, and that breaks the format a little.

```
const [showEmailError, setShowEmailError] = useState(false);
//code 
<div className='flex w-full flex-col space-y-2'>
        <label htmlFor='email' className='text-sm text-gray-600'>
          Email address
        </label>
        <input
          type='email'
          id='email'
          autoComplete='email'
          required
          className='peer relative block w-full appearance-none rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 invalid:text-pink-600 focus:z-10 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none  focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:invalid:border-pink-500 focus:invalid:ring-pink-500 sm:text-sm'
          value={email}
          onChange={e => {
            setEmail(e.target.value);
            setShowEmailError(false);
          }}
          onBlur={_ => setShowEmailError(true)}
        />
        <p className={`invisible mt-2 text-sm text-pink-600 ${
            email.length > 0 && showEmailError ? 'peer-invalid:visible' : ''}`}>
          Please provide a valid email address.
</div>
```

Current:

[image]

I tried adding `position: absolute` in the p tag like this:

```
<p className={`position: absolute invisible mt-2 text-sm text-pink-600 
    ${email.length > 0 && showEmailError ? 'peer-invalid:visible' : '' 
    }`}
>
```

Doing so, the warning appears like:

[image]

How to fix this?
Can I instead render whole p error tag error message conditionally? How to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using hidden and block instead of invisible and visible.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34098773)